# Jquery error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress, I created a function with jquery to read an xml file, but not read the file for some unknown reason.
URL: http://www.incakingdom.com/lista-de-paginas/machu-picchu/
The orange button (reservar ahora) is the one that calls the function, this is the javascript code:

```
    $("#reservar").click(function(){
        var pathactual = location.pathname;
                    alert("holaaaa");
    $.get("../../booking.xml", function(xml){
                    alert("cargó el xml");
        $(xml).find("urldirige").each(function() {              
              if($(this).find("url").text() == pathactual) {
                                        var text1="http://";
                document.location.href=text1+location.host+$(this).find("reserva").text();
              }
        });
    }); 

});
```

And this is the xml file:

[Image of xml content](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/4471/xmlik.jpg)

Please helpme thanks!

Comment: what is the problem? do you get an error?

Comment: i just tried it and i have been redirected to the correct page. One suggestion though will be to modify the relative path, and make `/booking.xml`

Comment: You can check the error, it should redirect to another url

Comment: Try to change all `$` to `jQuery` .. and try to use `jQuery.noCOnflict` and wrap in `document.ready()

Comment: Please could you pass some example of how you plan the solution? Obmerk Kronen